# Pandas lookup table using two arrays (index from the first array, column from the second array)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm struggling to vectorize a code that uses pandas lookup table, where the index is selected by the values from the first array and the column is selected by the values from the second array.

Let's say I have two numpy arrays `a` and `b` (they have the same shape):

```
codes = np.random.randint(1000, size=(4))
a_idx = np.random.randint(4, size=(6, 6))
a = codes[a_idx]
a[2, 1] = -999
a
Out[267]: 
array([[ 310,  310,   52,  310,  218,  310],
       [ 687,  310,  218,  310,  687,  687],
       [ 218, -999,  310,  218,   52,  687],
       [ 218,  218,  687,   52,  687,  310],
       [  52,  687,  687,   52,  687,  218],
       [  52,  218,   52,  687,  310,   52]])

b = np.random.randint(5, size=(6, 6))
b
Out[269]: 
array([[2, 4, 3, 2, 0, 4],
       [2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0]])
```

I also have a pandas lookup table:

```
lookup = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(1, 5),
                      'B': np.arange(11, 15),
                      'C': np.arange(21, 25)}, index=codes)
lookup.loc[-999] = 0
lookup
Out[275]: 
      A   B   C
 310  1  11  21
 687  2  12  22
 218  3  13  23
 52   4  14  24
-999  0   0   0
```

I have created a dictionary for pandas column names (different numbers can have the same letter):

```
b_dict = {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'B', 4:'A'}
```

I want to create a third array from the lookup table, where the index is selected by the value from array `a` and the column is selected from the array `b` (with the help of `b_dict`).
This is how it would be done by nested for loops:

```
res = np.empty_like(a)
for i, (row_a, row_b) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    for j, (aij, bij) in enumerate(zip(row_a, row_b)):
        res[i, j] = lookup.loc[aij, b_dict[bij]]
```

This would be the desired result:

```
res
Out[276]: 
array([[21,  1, 14, 21,  3,  1],
       [22,  1,  3, 21, 12,  2],
       [ 3,  0, 11, 13, 24,  2],
       [23, 23, 22, 24, 22, 11],
       [ 4, 12, 12, 14, 12, 23],
       [ 4, 13, 24, 22, 11,  4]])
```

Is there a faster (vectorized) way of doing this for large arrays using numpy or pandas, I would like to avoid nested loops?

EDIT: I changed the example to be more closer to the real problem.

Comment: You should be able to just do `lookup.values[a, b]`. You can search numpy advanced indexing for more info.

Comment: @Psidom an answer from you could help the OP, and possibly point him in the right direction for future related scenarios

Comment: @Psidom, thank you for the suggestion, it looks like I gave a too simplified example. Unfortunately, my acctual data is too complicated for a simple indexing. The index of the lookup table are not ordinal numbers but integer codes, the lookup table index looks more like `2, 156, 45, 893, 17,...`. Also arrays `a` and `b` have `nan` values, which I replaced by a single negative value...

Comment: @NinoKrvavica then please update the question with that information and a slightly more complex example closer to the real scenario.  We can assume that `a`, `b` and `lookup` have all the same shape, right?

Comment: @HarryPlotter, thank you, I updated the example, `a` and `b` have the same shape, but the `lookup` has a different shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten both arrays and use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to perform a label-based lookup, and reshape the result to the original shape of `a` and `b`

```
row_labels = a.ravel()
col_labels = pd.Series(b_dict)[b.ravel()].to_numpy()   
res = lookup.lookup(row_labels, col_labels).reshape(a.shape)
```

Using the same setup that your example

```
a = np.array([[ 310,  310,   52,  310,  218,  310],
              [ 687,  310,  218,  310,  687,  687],
              [ 218, -999,  310,  218,   52,  687],
              [ 218,  218,  687,   52,  687,  310],
              [  52,  687,  687,   52,  687,  218],
              [  52,  218,   52,  687,  310,   52]])

b = np.array([[2, 4, 3, 2, 0, 4],
              [2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0],
              [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
              [4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2],
              [0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0]])

b_dict = {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'B', 4:'A'}

lookup = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 0], 
                       'B': [11, 12, 13, 14, 0], 
                       'C': [21, 22, 23, 24, 0]},
                       index=[310, 687, 218, 52, -999])
```

**Output**

```
>>> row_labels

array([ 310,  310,   52,  310,  218,  310,  687,  310,  218,  310,  687,
        687,  218, -999,  310,  218,   52,  687,  218,  218,  687,   52,
        687,  310,   52,  687,  687,   52,  687,  218,   52,  218,   52,
        687,  310,   52])

>>> col_labels

array(['C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A',
       'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B',
       'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A'], dtype=object)

>>> res

array([[21,  1, 14, 21,  3,  1],
       [22,  1,  3, 21, 12,  2],
       [ 3,  0, 11, 13, 24,  2],
       [23, 23, 22, 24, 22, 11],
       [ 4, 12, 12, 14, 12, 23],
       [ 4, 13, 24, 22, 11,  4]])
```

---

[`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) is deprecated however, as stated in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html).

[image]

A better alternative, as suggested [in this official guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels), is to use [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html).

```
row_idx, row_labels = pd.factorize(a.ravel())
col_idx, col_labels = pd.factorize(pd.Series(b_dict)[b.ravel()].to_numpy())

res =(
    lookup.reindex(columns=col_labels, index=row_labels)   # reindex according to the encoding 
          .to_numpy()[row_idx, col_idx] # convert to 1D numpy array and use 'fancy index'
          .reshape(a.shape)  # reshape the 1D array to the original shape of a and b
)
```

**Output**

```
>>> row_idx

array([0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1,
       3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1])

>>> row_labels

array([ 310,   52,  218,  687, -999])

>>> col_idx

array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1])

>>> col_labels

array(['C', 'A', 'B'], dtype=object)

>>> res

array([[21,  1, 14, 21,  3,  1],
       [22,  1,  3, 21, 12,  2],
       [ 3,  0, 11, 13, 24,  2],
       [23, 23, 22, 24, 22, 11],
       [ 4, 12, 12, 14, 12, 23],
       [ 4, 13, 24, 22, 11,  4]])
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for, and it works great.
Unfortunately, I get a warning that `lookup` method is deprecated. I tryed using `DataFrame.melt` and `Dataframe.loc` instead, as suggested, but with no success. Any ideas how this could be done without the deprecated `lookup`?

Comment: @NinoKrvavica you are right! I updated the answer with the method suggested  [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels).

Comment: @NinoKrvavica does it solve your issue?

Comment: thank you, yes, this solves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate, `lookup.values[a, b]` yields the exact same results as `res` is after the loop fills it.

So essentially instead of this:

```py
res = np.empty_like(a)
for i, (row_a, row_b) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    for j, (aij, bij) in enumerate(zip(row_a, row_b)):
        res[i, j] = lookup.loc[aij, b_dict[bij]]
```

You can do this:

```py
res = lookup.values[a, b]
```

Output:

```py
>>> res
array([[ 4, 21,  4],
       [ 3,  4, 23],
       [23,  2, 11],
       [ 1, 13,  4]])

>>> lookup.values[a, b]
array([[ 4, 21,  4],
       [ 3,  4, 23],
       [23,  2, 11],
       [ 1, 13,  4]])

>>> res == lookup.values[a, b]
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```